# Detect If User coming from another WebSite after login

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc web application where user has to log-in to access some confidential data. 
So far everything is done but I am stuck at one point.

Consider following scenario:
**What is happening Now** : User has logged in and has been redirected to **HomePage**. Now User clicks on address bar and type **www.stackoverflow.com** and once SO is opened user hits **back** button of browser, Since User's session is active and hence allowed to access all data. 
**What Should Happen** : When a logged in user goes to another website and then comes back it must login again.

1. I have done some R&D on handling it with browser history but browser doesn't allow you to play with history.
2. I have tried handling this in Interceptor.
3. I have tried using HTTP REFERRER, but It doesn't tell me if User is coming back from another website as browser uses the same request which was used when user redirected after successful login and hence Referrer always returns me **Context/login** as referrer when user is back from another website.

Now, I am out of ideas, Please guide me to achieve this.
Thanks.

**Purpose of such an odd requirement**
well user can do whatever he wants to do, what I am trying to do is to make sure that if user forgets to logout and somehow moves to another website within same tab, then his data must be secure enough so that no one can see except himself

Comment: What an odd requirement, what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Also, what would happen should the user open a new tab?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? Referrer should work (but not securely or reliably) but there's nothing stopping the user from opening another tab, another window, using another browser to view another website. There's doesn't seem to be anything obvious to be gained by attempting to prevent the user from going somewhere else from your app's window.

Comment: thats not a potential security breach.. I think

Comment: @Kayaman, when there is highly confidential data we need to do such thing.

Comment: @npinti, well user can do whatever he wants to do, what I am trying to do is to make sure that if user forgets to logout and somehow moves to another website within same tab, then his data must be secure enough so that no one can see except himself

Comment: @Strider Which security standard is this requirement part of? Is it NIST or another entity?

Comment: @Kayaman, Its not I who decide such implementations, I am working for a Banking website and it's them(Bank guys) who want such thing which left me with no other choice :(

Comment: @Strider Of course it's not you. In a security sensitive situation you don't allow random people to come up with "standards". I'm somewhat surprised that in a bank environment you don't have stricter guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this perfectly, considering that the browser's back button isn't in any way different from performing a normal request.

The only remotely feasible way that this could be implemented in a very unreliable and overly complex way would be to add some javascript to every page, and when leaving the page check if the page is one of the bank pages or an external page. Then performing some logout (or store some token to local storage or similar, to indicate that the user has been somewhere else).

Or a better idea would be to talk to the bank people and discuss actual threats and then make sure that the system is designed to withstand `OWASP` attacks.

Do you have a security consultant or similar person in charge there? Your situation doesn't sound very secure, and I'm surprised you're allowed to work like that, considering how strongly regulated the financial sector is (at least in most of the countries I know).

Answer (score 1):

Options would include:

## Keepalive AJAX

Your site could make an AJAX request to keep a very short session timeout alive. For example, session timeout could be 10 seconds and your AJAX request could fire every 5 seconds. These values must be long enough to handle your users with the slowest connections.

Then, if a user navigates to a different site, the session will time out because no AJAX request has been made to keep the session alive.

For this to work best set the following response headers to disable caching:

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, no-transform
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

## Change navigation to POSTs

This is a big job and is best done when designing the site from scratch.

Rather than keep session state within a cookie, you use form POSTs for all site actions, including navigation:

```
<form method="post" action="/doAction">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="navigate" />
  <input type="hidden" name="params" value="page=aboutUs" />
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="123456789" />
</form>
```

As you can see there is a token in the form data. Once your form is submitted to navigate to another page, that token value is invalidated server side so it can't be reused. Then if the user clicks back the browser will ask them if they want to resubmit their POST data. Even if they do, as you have invalidated the random single use token on the server, they won't be recognised as being logged in and you can redirect them to the login page to start another session.

Token is a session identifier, however each page load will refresh the identifier and invalidate the old one.